# how price calculation is done in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

In open cart I was building a module and I needed to know how price calculations are done, and I came across this code

```
$price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], 
        $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
if ((float)$result['special']) {
    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate(
        $result['special'], 
        $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
} else {
    $special = false;
}                       
if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? 
           $result['special'] : $result['price']);
} else {
    $tax = false;
}
```

Actually I didn't get the idea what really happening here as I can see there is really no  difference between the `$price` and the `$special` and the `$tax` but there should be a reason why it is implemented this way.

I am sure i am missing something here any one explain to me how the price calculation is done in opencart?

Comment: hi there my question don't need revision as mush as it needs an answer i am really thankful for you revision but any one have an idea ?

Comment: I revised because it was impossible to read that thing. I think it's difficult to answer without context. One thing I can tell you for sure is that since I see a test on a float `if ((float)$result['special'])`, this has been written by an inexperienced programmer. To try to solve you've to see where that result["special"] comes from, print the values, and look at $this->tax->calculate method.

Comment: it wasn't me who wrote this, it is a part of te opencart source that i found and i can't understand why there is 3 variables while i can see that they can be a single one with the total, and why $special is float ?? do you have any idea ?

Comment: opencart is an mvc based so the implementation of those function are in other files that have no relationship with my module and i don't need to edit them cuz i will wreck other stuff that use them

Comment: I understand that is part of opencart and you can't modify the functions in other files, but you've to look at them to understand. Also try to print out the values and try to make sense of them. I can't from these lines of code only.

Comment: Just as intuition, special could be a discount, maybe. Tax is obviously the sales tax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4835/discussion-between-qchmqs-and-stivlo)

Comment: hmm, but I don't have other ideas. Also there is this line of code `$tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? 
$result['special'] : $result['price']);`, that will set tax to either special or price... weird, you're right..

Comment: actually there is no other file that contains that variable $tax and i   
dont understand where it comes from 2-> the currency->format() function only add the string of the currency $ or £ or €,calucalte only added the tax to the price and returns the new price 
obviously this is a simple to implement and hard to understand way of calculation any one can help ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the source, this is what I understand: `$price`, `$special` and `$tax` are variables that are passed to the view to display.

```
$price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], 
        $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
```

Every item has a price, so `$price` is always set. `$price` is ; the base price, with the applicable tax classes and tax applied.

```
if ((float)$result['special']) {
    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate(
        $result['special'], 
        $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
} else {
    $special = false;
}
```

An item might be on special. If it is, then `$special` is set to the base special price, with the same set of tax calculations applied to it. *(so that the view code can display both the original and the SPECIAL! price side-by-side)*

```
if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
    $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? 
           $result['special'] : $result['price']);
} else {
    $tax = false;
}
```

Not all installations have a tax configured. If it is, then `$tax` is set to be the base or base special price. *(so that the view code can display how much the item cost **before** tax. (it's a little bit illogical that `$tax` is the price without any tax on it)*

Make sense? If you need to know more about how price is calculated, look more closely at `tax->calculate()`. Otherwise it's

```
$taxed_price = $special ? $special : $price; 
$untaxed_price = (float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price'];
```

Comment: yes actually, the calculate only get the tax_id to and ask the DB for the rate of the tax to apply , and i think it is a silly thing that the untaxed price is called $tax,so this is why i wasn't able to understand it

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note for Mr Trick's answer. The three parameters of $this->tax->calculate() are

> $value, $tax_class_id, $calculate = true

The third of which is not necessary, but in the original code, it gets the global config value of whether or not tax should be applied (since you can disable it in the settings). It's worth also noting that the tax object has changed between versions (I think it was 1.5.1.2 that it changed last) so if you're wanting to make it backward compatible, it's something to consider

Comment: don't mean to be rude but I DONT GIVE A DAMN ABOUT BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY :),just Kidding ill upvote this :p

Comment: Haha, well if you're planning on reselling it, you'd best be willing to be compatible back to at least 1.4.9 :)

Comment: actually it is already sold to a customer (so i am doing this as a special module for his own opencart no need for backward compa) :-)